# Radio buttons not working as they should

Tags: php, html

I have these two codes.  When i submit my form, it always default to a checked no

```
<td><input type="radio" onclick="selbustbl(1)" name="rdo2" id="busyes" value="yes" <? if(isset($_POST['rdo2']) == 'yes') echo " checked";  ?> />Yes</td>

<td><input type="radio" onclick="selbustbl(2)" name="rdo2" id="busno" value="no" <? if(isset($_POST['rdo2']) == 'no') echo "checked";  ?> />No</td>
```

Please help

Answer (score 1):

`isset()` returns `true` or `false`. Not yes or no. So you need to check to see if it is set first and then check its value.

```
if(isset($_POST['rdo2']) == 'yes')
```

should be

```
if(isset($_POST['rdo2']) && $_POST['rdo2'] == 'yes')
```